# How to create a symmetric matrix of complex numbers?

Tags: matlab, matrix, toeplitz

I want to create a symmetric matrix with complex elements in Matlab using the toeplitz command. However if I provide the toeplitz command with complex entries it returns a Hermitian matrix, that is, the signs of the imaginary parts are reversed above and below the diagonal.

```
matrix = toeplitz([ 1 + 1i, 2 + 2i])

matrix =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i
   2.0000 - 2.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

How can I create a symmetric matrix where the signs of the imaginary parts are the same above and below the diagonal like this:

```
matrix =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i
   2.0000 + 2.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to pass your input **two times** to [**`toeplitz`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html), because you actually want to create an *unsymmetric toeplitz matrix*, where the unsymmetric part is the conjugate complex of the naturally conjugate complex part of the Toeplitz matrix:

```
X = [ 1 + 1i, 2 + 2i, 3 + 3i]
matrix = toeplitz( X, X )
```

---

```
matrix =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
   2.0000 + 2.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i
   3.0000 + 3.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i   1.0000 + 1.0000i
```